# Struct pack python to arduino

Tags: python, struct, serial-port, arduino

I am trying to send x and y coordinates from my Python on my Raspberry Pi to a [Arduino Nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems#Official). Currently, I am using serial communication, packing the coordinates with struct.pack(), but my Arduino is not receiving the coordinates the way I would expect.

```
import serial
import struct

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 115200, timeout = 1)

def sendpacket(x,y) # x and y are integers
    packet = struct.pack('BsBs',x, ',' , y, ',')
    print packet
    print ord(packet)
    ser.write(packet)
```

I have inserted commas so that the Arduino can tell the difference between x's and y's. I know that the Arduino can only read one byte at a time, which is why I was packing the data before sending it, but I don't really understand what is going on.

I know struct.pack() converts my packet to Unicode, or at least it appears to from my above print statements. Is that what is actually being send over serial? How should I read this in the Arduino code?

Alternatively, is there a better way to send/receive xy coordinates over serial?

I am a beginner, I know/understand very little of what I am trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! How _is_ it receiving your coordinates if it's "not the way you expect?" Always be clear on both the expected behavior and the actual behavior. (Also heads up: there's an [Arduino Stack Exchange](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/), which may be useful for you if you're a beginner in Arduino).